# Snakemake: Random FileNotFoundError for a shared file in a rule when submitting jobs in parallel

Tags: jobs, snakemake

I have the following rule:

```py
rule run_example:
    input:
        counts=config['output_dir'] + "/Counts/skin.txt"
    params:
        chrom=lambda wildcards: gene_chrom()[wildcards.SigGene]
    output:
        config['out_refbias'] + "/{SigGene}.txt"
    script:
        "Scripts/run_example.R"      
 
with SigGene=["gene1", "gene2"]

I define the following function:

def gene_chrom(File=config['output_dir'] + "/genes2test.txt", sep=" "):
    """ Makes a dictionary with keys gene and values chromosome from a file with first col gene_id and second col CHROM """
    data=pd.read_csv(File, sep=sep)
    keys=list(data['gene_id'])
    values=[str(x) for x in data['CHROM']]
    dic=dict(zip(keys,values))
    return dic
```

I submit the rule to a cluster to run jobs in parallel. For **some jobs** I get the following **error message**:

FileNotFoundError in line 67 of Snakefile:
[Tue Jun 23 09:47:16 2020] [Errno 2] File b'/scratch/genes2test.txt' does not exist: b'/scratch/genes2test.txt'

The file exist and is shared among all instances of the rule. Most jobs were able to read the file and run to completion but some failed with above error message.

Comment: How many jobs do you start? Could it be related to the max number of open files on the operating system? P.s. you could just execute gene_chrom, store it in some variable, and pass that to params. That way you do not have to read the file multiple times.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, even with 4 jobs I have seen the issue.